# RxJava. Read file to observable

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am totally new to RxJava and reactive programming. 
I have an assignment where i must read file and store it to Observable. I have tried to make a Callable with BufferedReader inside and use Observable.fromCallable(), but it didn't work much.

Could you please show me how can i do that?

I am using RxJava 2.0.

Answer (score 6):

A basic solution where I use a nested class `FileObservableSource` to produce the data and then defer the creation of the Observable until an Observer subscribes:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.ObservableSource;
import io.reactivex.Observer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Observable<String> observable = Observable.defer(() -> new FileObservableSource("pom.xml"));
        observable.subscribe(
                line -> System.out.println("next line: " + line),
                        Throwable::printStackTrace,
                        () -> System.out.println("finished")
                );
    }

    static class FileObservableSource implements ObservableSource<String> {

        private final String filename;

        FileObservableSource(String filename) {
            this.filename = filename;
        }

        @Override
        public void subscribe(Observer<? super String> observer) {
            try {
                Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).forEach(observer::onNext);
                observer.onComplete();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                observer.onError(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would this behave under backpressure? Let's say I've a subscriber observing on a different thread that is processing each line slower than its read.

Comment: it would behave badly. no backpressure handling here. I would use  reactive stream implementation for that, but this question was about a basic example.

Answer (score 3):

for Java 8, BufferedReader has a file stream and the iterator which you can use in tandem with RxJava. https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-stream-rx-java

you can get a Flowable using the following code

```
 Flowable.fromIterable(bufferedReader.lines()::iterator)
```

I use Flowable and Single to be more concise, it'll still work with Observable.
the code snippet is an example of how I read each single line from the buffered reader.

```
try (
       FileReader fr = new FileReader("./folder1/source.txt");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 

       //e.g. i write the output into this file
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("./folder1/destination.txt");
       BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)
        ) { 

      //=========================================
      //calling br.lines() gives you the stream. 
      //br.lines()::iterator returns you the iterable
      //=========================================
      Flowable.fromIterable(br.lines()::iterator)

         //at this point you can do what you want for each line
                 //e.g. I split long strings into smaller Flowable<String> chunks.
                .flatMap(i -> splitLine(i))
                 //e.g. I then use the output to query an external server with retrofit.
                 //     which returns me a Single<String> result
                .flatMapSingle(i -> handlePinyin(pr, i))  

                .subscribe(
                        //I save the results from server to destination.txt
                        py -> appendToFile(bw, py),
                        //print and quit if error
                        err -> print("ERROR " + err), 
                        () -> print("Completed!"));


}catch (IOException e) {
        print("Error " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar to [this implementation](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/davidmoten/rx/internal/operators/OnSubscribeInputStream.java).

And then that class is used [here](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/davidmoten/rx/Bytes.java) in this way:

```
public static Observable<byte[]> from(InputStream is, int size) {
     return Observable.create(new OnSubscribeInputStream(is, size));
}
```

Eventually you can use it:

```
Observable<byte[]> chunks = Bytes.from(file, chunkSize);
```

More details [here](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras).

Comment: But what if i dont know chunksize and need to read file line by line?

Comment: Then you should adapt that code, converting your `InputStream` into a `BufferedReader` an then using `readLine` method.