# How to create a line-based observable from InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, reactive-programming

Sorry for the basic question...
I have a function that takes an InputStream with the content of a file, and returns a list of objects, let's say Person.

Every line of the input file contains a person, so I want to parse it by line.
Nothing difficult but... this time I want to use reactive programming.

Something like:

```
public List<Person> parse(final InputStream is) throws IOException {
    return
    //create an observable which will split the input in many lines, "\n"
            .map(Person::new)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

I miss the commented step, that is: creating an observable that is not byte based, but line-based.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJava. Read file to observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442480/rxjava-read-file-to-observable)

Comment: I saw that question, but I could not implement Flowable.fromIterable(...) nor Observable.toIterable(...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `stream` of `String` using the method [`lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) of `BufferedReader`:

> Returns a `Stream`, the elements of which are lines read from this `BufferedReader`.

with a code similar to this one:

```
Stream<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, cs)).lines();
```

So your code should be something like:

```
public List<Person> parse(final InputStream is) throws IOException {
    CharSet cs = ... // Use the right charset for your file
    Stream<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, cs)).lines();
    return  lines
            .map(Person::new)   
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: I just found a similar solution, but I didn't use the charset: BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        return br.lines()
                .map(...)....;

Is it the same? The file is in (ugly) ASCII.

Comment: @fresko Yes if the file has been written using the default charset of your JVM, the constructor without a char set "uses the default charset"

Comment: the question author wants to use reactive programming. Your solution does not use reactive programming.

Answer (score 2):

According to your code, you don't need to implement an Observable of lines, since you want afterwards to use Java's Streams. You can't move back from Rx to java streams.

But if you want to base completely to Observables, you can start with this:

```
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            Observable<String> linesObs = Observable.from(reader.lines()::iterator);
            // In rxjava v2:
            // Observable<String> linesObs = Observable.fromIterable(reader.lines()::iterator);
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Minor correction here: this should be `Observable.fromIterable(`...`)`, not `Observable.from(`...`)`

Comment: I stand corrected. I was using the old rx.Observable, while you're talking about io.reactivex.Observable.